# Why does TypeScript's Omit not enforce the value of the omitted properties?

Tags: typescript, interface, strong-typing, typescript-utility

**Background:** (can be skipped)

I was fiddling around to make some `update(person: Person)` statement more usable by allowing a subset of properties it should update. I was thinking there are 2 options:

- The id is passed explicitly to the update method as the first argument, and then `Partial<Person>` or `Omit<Person, 'id'>` as the 2nd argument.
- Or, the update method's signature remains as is, with only 1 input arg, and enforces that the `id` property is in the object provided.

So `Omit` seems like a good candidate to me, but the keys to omit can be of any string value.

**Question:**

Why does TypeScript not enforce the value of the keys provided to `Omit` ? Is there any good use not to which I am overseeing?

See the following code

```
export interface Person {
  id: string;
  age: number;
  name: string;
}

type UpdatePerson = Omit<Person, 'whatEver'>; // Why does 'whatEver' not cause compile issues?
type UpdatePerson2 = Pick<Person, 'id'> & Partial<Person>; // Great, a valid key is enforced here
type UpdatePerson3 = Pick<Person, 'thisDoesNotCompile'> & Partial<Person>; // This line fails compilation as that property isn't part of the interface
```

For now I go with `update(person: UpdatePerson)` and `type UpdatePerson = Pick<Person, 'id'> & Partial<Person>;`. This makes all properties optional, and the id mandatory.

Comment: I'm not sure why but `Omit`'s type definition doesn't enforce the 2nd type parameter to be a `keyof <FirstParameter>`. You could use a custom `Omit` type definition like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBTQGcIk4BvAWACg5EATALjiJimQHMBuGuzD4MyQBXALYAjND1pwkmUYJZtO0gL40aMAJ5g8AeVEIYAZWXYYAHgAqAGjgBpOKFRJ6ROAGtgWiOjhWAPjgAXgo4AG18RDIAURBsABthemALLx8-WwcAgF1mK0icrjh1ak0dPABVMHpMVEIoEjJQgyNTdnMLBqa7ACIAdwALOpiANzRegOkgA)

Comment: For future dupe-closing (or to prove validity of the question), a very similar question [was asked previously with upvotes but no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916501/why-is-omit-not-typesafe).

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30825

Comment: @MikeS Having just found that myself, I think one of us should post that as an answer with a quote from [Daniel Rosenwasser's Apr 15 comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30825#issuecomment-483464598). Would you like to, since you beat me to the comment?

Comment: @JeffBowman I haven't gone through the issue in detail and I'm afraid I won't be able to for a bit, so I dont mind if you formulated an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

In short, this behavior was selected so the [built-in `Omit`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cc450cf820f682f19b4a3213e6bc1cea475a5337/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1516) could be most compatible with existing DefinitelyTyped libraries. Those libraries were already split on whether Omit should be strict, and picking a looser Omit prevented those existing libraries from breaking at the expense of slightly less compiler safety and autocomplete for code yet to be written.

---

For background: this was requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#30825](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30825), with [this response](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30825#issuecomment-483464598) from [DanielRosenwasser](https://github.com/DanielRosenwasser):

> It seems like the constrained `Omit` type is going to make at least half of users unhappy based on declarations within DefinitelyTyped. We've decided to go with the more permissive built-in which your own constraints can build on.

And these from language co-author [Ryan Cavanaugh](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh):

> I have to clear up this misconception. There were 12 different definitions of Omit on DT and the two most popular definitions differed on whether or not to constraint [sic] the key: [snip]

> You can pick at the numbers and try to declare a democratic majority or something, but the reality is that only one definition *doesn't* break a substantial portion of people.

It is a popular request with duplicates [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73164042/why-does-typescripts-omit-not-enforce-the-value-of-the-omitted-properties) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32376), and corresponding concise strict equivalents are easy to write/derive and also [available in other libraries like `type-zoo`](https://github.com/pelotom/type-zoo/blob/eab30a98ab77612ae0a0e51b91456dcbf4b12257/types/index.d.ts#L33).